# Insert Row based on user input in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Excel 2010
Searching for macro to insert rows based on user input. User providing Row number to insert row.

1. Based on user input - Row to be inserted in multiple sheets ( accounts, process,data,...and so on) have 19 sheets
2. Copy formula and format from above row and autofill down.

So far, able to get below code for single sheet based on selection of cell

Hoping to get some answers...

```
Sub Insert_Row()
    If Selection.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    With Selection
        .EntireRow.Copy
        .Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
Sub Insert_Row()
    Dim SelRow as Integer, i as Integer, j as Integer
    If Selection.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    SelRow = Selection.Row
    On Error Goto nonNumeric
    j = InputBox("What row to insert data into?", "Pick a row")
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo NumericEntry

nonNumeric:
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox("Please try again with a number.")
    Exit Sub

NumericEntry:
    For i = 1 to 19
        Sheets(1).Select
        Rows(SelRow).copy
        Sheets(i).Select
        Rows(j).Insert
        On Error Resume Next
            Rows(j).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, Rows are same on all 19 sheets. As per initial question , There must be pop up for user input asking after which row number new line to be inserted? Based on user input - Must insert new row in all 19 sheets and auto fill formula and formatting in all 19 sheets

Comment: Updated my previous comment.

Comment: Getting Run-time error "1004"  - Row to be inserted in multiple sheets ( accounts, process,data,...and so on) have 19 sheets